# Best method for displaying a tree list using CSS only (no images or JS, example inside)

Tags: html, css

I want to display something like this on a HTML page:
[image]

With the restriction of using only CSS. **The main problem lies in making these:** `｜└ ├` "branches".

The example above was a solution I done myself. Each branch has the same width and consists of:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

The trick is to turn the borders of `<li>` black accordingly. An image to show this (just a quick mock up)
[image]

A problem I've encountered is turning the border white to match the background instead of transparent (apparently CSS has some problem with transparent borders on lists).

**My question is: what's the most simplest solution? Is there a better way to do this?**

EDIT: Some requirements:

- The branch must have fixed width but the height must grow accordingly with the height of the table cell.
- The two `li` elements must take up half of the row's height each such that the `-` in `├` will always be in the middle.

EDIT2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Tree_list did a little research. Alas, they use images for branches.

**PS: As requested http://jsfiddle.net/q3zdB/2/**

Comment: What's your current CSS? (For what it's worth I'm quite impressed) Would you be able to show us your current solution in a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), as a starting point?

Comment: @DavidThomas I only have a screenshot of my implementation and what the code is from memory. I'll try ask for access to the code at work, stick around a bit and I'll post on JSFiddle.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this require *just* HTML/CSS or is JavaScript allowed at all? (I realise that pure HTML/CSS would way more impressive (and preferable to all), but it might be beyond the ability of the tools themselves.)

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah pure HTML/CSS. No JS allowed.

Comment: @DavidThomas Done: http://jsfiddle.net/q3zdB/ I wrote this 2 years ago, if you can make improvements please do :P

Comment: Sorry, I didn't wait for your JS Fiddle before putting together an answer, so...I'm not sure how useful the answer would be to you, now.

Comment: No problem, any creative solutions are welcome mate :)

Answer (score 33):

The best I can come up with for this is some (unfortunately regrettable) nesting and use of generated content (so it does require a pretty up-to-date browser, so [IE < 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15) isn't going to look terribly pretty), however, that said, given the HTML:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
li div {
  padding-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
li div::before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 0.75em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: 0 none transparent;
  border-right: 0 none transparent;
}
ul > li:last-child {
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div>Level 1</div></li>
  <li><div>Level 1</div>
    <ul>
      <li><div>Level 2</div></li>
      <li><div>Level 2</div>
        <ul>
          <li><div>Level 3</div></li>
          <li><div>Level 3</div></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><div>Level 1</div></li>
</ul>
```

We get this:

[image: Link to the JS Fiddle demo.]

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ljnhc/1/)

Comment: Thanks, can this be used in conjunction with a table though? I think nesting them won't allow this. I've updated my JSFiddle demo to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/q3zdB/2/

Comment: So my solution just stacks a bunch of branches in each table row. The main problem here is not to worry about nested levels etc I have written a php script that spits out what branch I should have from a data source. It's rather how I can draw those lines without using borders.

Comment: @meiryo: I may have misunderstood the scope of the original question, then. Looking at what you want to do, it may require an SVG based approach (which would likely require JavaScript, but can be done without). I'll have another look in a while and, if I'm able, will post a better answer after some consideration.

Comment: That would be awesome, thanks. I tried using a @font-face approach but had difficulties stretching the font vertically.

Comment: can you make this collapsible? or should i create new question?

Comment: If you do not want to align the tree leaf in the middle of a multi-row list item, just remove "bottom: 50%" and add a height instead

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fork of David's solution eliminating the need for the extra `<div>` in each `<li>`:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
li {
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
li li {
  margin-left: 0;
}
li::before {
  content:'┗';
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -9px;
}
ul > li:last-child {
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Level 1</li>
  <li>Level 1
    <ul>
      <li>Level 2</li>
      <li>Level 2
        <ul>
          <li>Level 3</li>
          <li>Level 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Level 1</li>
</ul>
```

[Demo on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/layewuf/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: This is great, issue is that it seems not to be possible to disable font smoothing, which looks bad on the last child

Comment: Unfortunately it looks quite broken on a mobile device...